# Flutter BarChart Show DomainFn Values Vertically

Tags: flutter

As i mentioned on title, I'm having trouble on BarCharts. There are 20 columns for barChart and they are overlapping eachother. How can i print them vertically so that way they wont overlap ?

```
Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesBarData,
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                )
                ,)
              ],)
            ),
          )
```

[image: how do they overlap]

**Edit 1 :** Thanks for answer after i applied it. It indeed rotated column names but this time my chart became too small. I've tried to give margin from container but eventhough chart went down to middle, it didn't get bigger

```
domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
  renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(labelRotation: 90),
), //90 or 270 to make it vertical
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** After a little more research i've done this but lastly i need to fit DomainFn values to their bars. Right now, It's a little bit on the right side.

```
Expanded(child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesBarData,
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
      // Rotation Here,
      labelRotation: -90,
      labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before,

    ),
  ),
                )
                ,)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done what i need to do. Thanks for help and i wanted to share if somebody look for answer.

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesBarData,
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
      // Rotation Here,
      labelRotation: -90,
      labelOffsetFromTickPx: -5,
      labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before,

    ),
  ),
                )
                ,)
              ],)
            ),
          )
```

labelAnchor and labelRotation helped me to print vertically without shrinking the barChart. After that i used labelOffsetFromTickPx to fit label positions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to rotate the domains

```
domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
  renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(labelRotation: 90),
), //90 or 270 to make it vertical
```

Full code

```
return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: charts.BarChart(
                  _seriesBarData,
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  domainAxis: charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
                    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(labelRotation: 90),
                  ),
                )
                ,)
              ],)
            ),
          );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but something went wrong. I've updated my answer. I would be thankful if you check it out. Btw can i move the column names a little bit right to fit them perfectly ? It looks like they out of order.

Comment: Check this variable _seriesBarData, It may give extra spaces to the domain names, for the bar graph size, I think you dont need to use column or center widget.

Comment: even without center and columns there is no change :(

Comment: You have to use expanded widget outside the container, not inside. Also remove the other unnecessary widgets.

Comment: Is there any way to set the offset or something?